# What's the command same as copy as curl in chrome browser

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, curl

I created a script to routinely download page from my carrier website this will gather my remaining internet quota.

I use copy as curl feature from chrome browser, paste them to my script, it works.

But when i run them like 1 hour later it not working. I suspect this is because the cookies expired, is there any terminal command to get curl request exactly same as copy as curl from chrome?

This is my curl command:

```
curl 'https://my.smartfren.com/mysmartfren_home' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/72.0.3626.121 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
    --compressed \
    -H 'Referer: https://my.smartfren.com/mysmartfren_login' \
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
    -H 'Cookies:' \
    -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
    -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
    &> /dev/stdout \
    | tee -a $LOG
```

i removed cookies here bcs of security

Comment: How is this in any way about Ubuntu?

Comment: i want to run it from shell script

Comment: Not working how? Please [edit] and add any error messages, in full. What are you doing exactly? Can you post the contents of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cookies all you need, then you could try replacing cookies parameter with your actual updated cookies, to do this you need to login to the site through cURL.

Considering this is a script you created, then we'll use `$COOKIES` variable to define the updated cookies file.

Open inspect element and crawl through the form, look for occurence of id of user and password field—substitute the result to below cURL command.

```
COOKIES="cookies.txt"
curl -c $COOKIES --data "user=YOURUSER&pass=YOURPASS" https://login.site.com
```

The cookies produced can be used for your main cURL command, something like this should suffice.

```
curl 'http://site.com' -H 'Referer: http://login.site.com' -b $COOKIES
```

Where `$COOKIES` used as cookies parameter, just remember you have to put `$COOKIES` file same folder as where the script reside—or other place you need to specify. Well, you get the idea